# Emacs fails to load org-id at start

Tags: org-mode

When I start the emacs and try to customize variable `org-id-locations-file` it can't find it.

But I can describe variable `org-id-locations-file`. After describing the variable, if I run customize variable again on the same variable, now it finds it.

So my issue is, any variable with prefix `org-id-` is not found when trying to customize variable until I first describe it.

Customizing `org-id` group works.

Thinking back to what I have changed, I set `org-id-extra-files` to `nil` from a variable.

PS. By describing variable I mean: `M-x describe-variable` and by customize variable I mean `M-x customize-variable`.

PS I fixed this problem by adding `(require 'org-id)`. Now I need to see if linking by id works as expected.

Comment: The question is rambling and evolving. Please remove anything irrelevant to what you are really asking, and clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

`describe-variable` was enhanced a few releases back so as to try and automatically load the corresponding package (after guessing which one it is).  But this mechanism has not (yet) been applied to `customize-variable`, so please do `M-x report-emacs-bug` to request that new feature.